# System of equations: Incidence matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I've got the following system of equations:
$$ Mx = B^T d$$
where $$M = B^T C B \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$$, $$B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$$ an incidence matrix of a closed, connected network, $$ C \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$$ the indicator matrix and $$ d \in \mathbb R^n, x \in \mathbb R^m$$.

I know and already prooved that M is symmetric and positive semidefinite and that C is symmetric positive definite. In addition, I know that the system of equations doesn't have a unique solution.

Now my question: How does the system of equation looks like if I erase the i-th row and the i-th column of M?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: 3 Questions 1) Is your graph oriented (i.e. its incidence matrix entries are 0,1,-1) or not ? 2) Is $n$ the number of vertices and $m$ the number of arcs ? 3) What do you mean by "indicator matrix" for a graph ?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. I try to answer them: 
1) The graph is oriented, since our incidence matrices always have entries 0, 1, or -1.
2) Exactly! :)
3) I translated badly, sorry. C is the conducting matrix. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: What do you mean by "look like"? It looks just like the other but with a variable set to 0 and ignoring one equation...

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik That is what, concretely?

Comment: You mean the interpretation pf that in terms of the underlying graph?

Comment: Well in other words I look for a solution of the system of equations if I erase the i-th row and the i-th column of M.